# ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar un botón en React Native?

Tags: react-native

Tengo un botón de login en mi aplicación y quiero que aparezca deshabilitado al principio. Esto me funciona pues:

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} 
           disabled={this.state.isUserLoggedIn || !this.state.name}>
```

Sin embargo, según en qué casos, me gustaría que este valor de disabled fuera permanente, sin depender de condiciones.

¿Cómo deshabilito un botón?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes decir [`disabled={true}`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#disabled):

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} 
           disabled={true}>
```

Como dice el manual que enlazo arriba:

> Si su valor es verdadero, deshabilita todas las interacciones para este componente.

Comment: Esto res realmente lo mismo que el esta preguntando, si es evaluado `true` entonces esta disabled

Answer (score 1):

Sí he entendido bien lo que necesitas puedes usar una tercera variable y un poco de lógica.

Por ejemplo:

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={mainState && (!this.state.name || this.isUserLoggedIn)} />
```

De esta forma sí estableces la variable mainState como 'false', independientemente de lo que tengan el resto de variables, el botón quedará deshabilitado.

Answer (score 0):

Tu realmente si quieres que el boton tenga condiciones para que este **disabled** o no, porque si haces algo asi:

```js
<TouchableOpacity disabled={true}/>
```

nunca mas tendras accesso a cambiarlo, so que lo que puedes hacer es lo mismo que tenias:

```js
<TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.isUserLoggedIn}/>
```

o algo asi

```js
{ this.state.isUserLoggedIn ? <TouchableOpacity/> : <View/> }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TouchableOpacity` extension de `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, por lo que sólo puede utilizar la propiedad: `disabled`

Te invito a leer la documentacion [React Native Touchable](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#disabled)